# search with transliteration

Tags: search

How I can implement transliterated searches?
for example if someone write in latin characters these to be converted to another coding characters?

How I can instruct drupal that latin character a corresponds to another language character?

Or how i can integrate google transliteraion api in drupal search?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to embed google transliteration api in to drupal? http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/language/transliterate/overview.html

Comment: a similar question here http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Searching-with-wrong-keyboard-layout-or-using-translit-td1782609.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by implementing hook_search_preprocess() and integrating with the Transliteration module.  Example code is below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_search_preprocess().
 *
 * Transliterates text added to the search index and user submitted search
 * keywords.
 */
function mymodule_search_preprocess($text) {
  return transliteration_get($text, '', language_default('language'));
}
?>
```

There is a more complete example and discussion at http://drupal.org/node/1058064.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be great if someone could write this as a complete module.

Comment: You're welcome.  I would post a comment to a link in the answer so the Transliteration maintainer integrates it into the module.

Comment: I hope it will get done.